# JS: Change ScrollTop to display browser widths

Tags: javascript, elementor

I have a script in my WordPress site ([https://deganiagroup.com/}](https://deganiagroup.com/%7D) where clicking one of the navigation button provides a scroll to effect to the proper place on the screen. Because of a sticky header, I had to add a fixed scrollTop value, which either works right on desktop but not on mobile, or the other way around.

This is because the header's height changes depending on browser width because the header itself changes. So a fixed height doesn't really work here.

Can I expand this script to offer break points so the scrollTop value changes based on header height no matter what the browser width is?

This script was meant for Elementor page builders, but realistically it could be for anything involving scrolling on click.

Javascript:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
    if ( ! defined( 'ELEMENTOR_VERSION' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
            // Add space for Elementor Menu Anchor link
            $( window ).on( 'elementor/frontend/init', function() {
                elementorFrontend.hooks.addFilter( 'frontend/handlers/menu_anchor    /scroll_top_distance', function( scrollTop ) {
                    return scrollTop - 121; // Scroll to fixed value
                } );
            } );
        } );
    </script>
    <?php
} );
```

Comment: If your header height is variable, then you can have CSS variables that reference it.  `:root { --header-height: 40px; }  @media (min-width: 800px) { :root { --header-height: 50px; } }` and the like.  And then when you want to use it in your css you can just `var(--header-height)` to use the value

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the height directly insite the function:

```
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    var $siteHeader  = $('#site-header');
    
    // Add space for Elementor Menu Anchor link
    $(window).on('elementor/frontend/init', function() {
      elementorFrontend.hooks.addFilter('frontend/handlers/menu_anchor    /scroll_top_distance', function(scrollTop) {
        return scrollTop - $siteHeader.height();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I just updated functions.php with your code, but I don't see any change. Can you check?

Like the distancec should be around 157px on desktop and 121 on mobile.

Comment: I took some time to look at it and set break points in the code to see what's happening. This `return scroll...` line is never called. The filter is never called. Here's why: In Elementor's code, it's supposed to do it when you click on a given set of links. It tries to find those links by using a CSS selector which it looks for in `settings.selectors.links`, but that selector is not set, so it gives up: https://imgur.com/a/BnVvUYp (`handleAnchorLinks` not called bc no selector) I tried to look at the docs, but did not find how to set this setting. The value should probably be `".menu-link"`